# Need fix for the codesniffer warning "The use of function sleep() is discouraged (Magento2.Functions.DiscouragedFunction.Discouraged)"

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.3, best-practice

When I run PHP Code sniffer on my code, I see the below warning.

```
WARNING | The use of function sleep() is discouraged (Magento2.Functions.DiscouragedFunction.Discouraged)
```

Which class method provides an alternative for the `sleep()` method in Magento 2 framework that fixes the above warning and follows the magento best practice.

Comment: Have you found solution? I'm facing same issue. Thanks.

Comment: I found a temporary solution. I answered it here. Please check.

Answer (score 2):

Modify the code from

```
sleep(<time>);
```

to

```
// phpcs:ignore Magento2.Functions.DiscouragedFunction
sleep(<time>);
```

This is just a temporary solution where in the codesniffer ignores the evaluation of the discouraged function when prepended with the comment `phpcs:ignore Magento2.Functions.DiscouragedFunction`

Comment: It is just ignore the code during codesniffer. Try solution given by me. Hope it works for you. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Nitkin, I have used // phpcs:ignore Magento2.Functions.DiscouragedFunction which you have recommended for html_entity_decode() method  but when I am generating report still the same warning is appearing. can you pls advise

Answer (score 2):

I have found solution. We have to use `usleep` function which is working same like `sleep` function.

Only difference is that `usleep` function works in microseconds so you have to covert second into microsecond and it's work like a charm.

For example:-

```
sleep(2); //2 seconds delay here
usleep(2000000);  //2000000 microseconds = 2 seconds
```

Comment: Hahahah this is Magento !!! In a couple of days they'll add usleep as well hahaha